# OnClick restore text

Tags: forms, onclick, textarea

Basically what I want to be able to click reset on this form and always have it return to a particular default setting. Have found many forms that will clear the textarea altogether but not return the value to a preset.  Here is what I have that kinda work but the whole kicker is that it won't work in a stand alone HTA window. It tries to open the HTA over again when I try to reset the text.

```
<FORM>
    <TEXTAREA NAME="textarea" ROWS="10" COLS="30">
        DEFAULT TEXT THAT WILL REAPPEAR IN TEXT AREA WHEN RESET IS CLICKED
    </TEXTAREA>
    <INPUT TYPE="submit" value="Reset">
</FORM>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "placeholder" attribute to set a default content:

```
<name="textarea" placeholder="Default content">Default content</textarea>
```

> The placeholder attribute specifies a short hint that describes the expected value of a text area.

Comment: that worked, thank you so much. I just had to add the /r for the carriage returns in the text area field and it was good to go ! thank you again :)

Comment: @Aaron Koon please accept the answer as correct so that other can use it also.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
<textarea name="textarea" id="textarea" rows="10" cols="30"></textarea>
<input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="resetTextArea('Default Text That Will Reappear In text Area When Reset is Clicked')" />
</form>
<script>
function resetTextArea(msg){
document.getElementById('textarea').value=msg;
}
</script>
```